# Establishing a relationship between the author and the website / article

Tags: schema.org, markup, author

I have integrated the author's markup into an article markup. To link the author to the article in a semantic context, I use the mainEntityOfPage attribute. The link to the article is marked as "WebPage" and has the property "@id".

is this method correct, to establish the relationship between a person (the author) and a web page (the article) with the "mainEntityOfPage"-attribute?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "headline": "Definite Proof that Clark Kent isn't Superman",
  "datePublished": "2022-03-07",
  "description": "Why does everyone think that Clark Kent might be Superman? He is not and here is proof.",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Lois Lane",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/blog/lois-lane.html", 
    "image": "https://www.example.com/blog/portrait-lois.jpg",
    "email": "content.editor@example.com",
    "jobTitle": "Content Editor",
    "sameAs": [
      "https://www.facebook.com/lois.lane",
      "https://www.linkedin.com/lois.lane",
      "https://www.instagram.com/lois.lane"
    ],
    "mainEntityOfPage":{       
    "@type": "WebPage",       
    "@id": "https://www.example.com/blog/clark-kent-not-superman.html"     
    }
  }
}
</script>
```